# PHP: persistent SQL syntax error when using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb, syntax-error

I'm trying to select from a table using a particular sorting, based on a query string that determines both the column to sort by, and the order to sort it in. This results in a SQL syntax error, but I really don't understand what the problem is. I get the same error no matter what I try:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

This is the code:

```
$stmt = $db->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY :sortBy :sortOrder");
$stmt->bindParam(':sortBy', $sortBy);
$stmt->bindParam(':sortOrder', $sortOrder);
$stmt->execute();
$media = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

What's so bizarre is that when I replace the :placeholders from the query with actual text, it works:

```
$stmt = $db->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY title ASC");
```

This puts the table data in $media as intended, but of course this way I can't actually change the sorting. I've made very sure the variables $sortBy and $sortOrder are set correctly; that's definitely not the problem.

This is on a local XAMPP server using MariaDB 10.4.16. What on earth is going on here?

Comment: You cannot use placeholders at all places within an sql statement and hope that they will work - they are intended for specific uses and it looks like that is not one of them

Comment: Its the `:sortBy and :sortOrder` that is the issue. You cannot use a parameter there or for tablenames or column names. The reason: The prepare submits the query for compilation, MySQL (or anything else) cannot compile something if it is not sure what to compile because key parts of a statement are missing.

Comment: You will need to inject `ASC` or `DESC` for the sort order. Make sure you hardwire these (i.e. don't use user input directly).